# VBA noob, how to single out a unique value in multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, vba

I have 9 arrays which hold 8 values each:

```
all(1,1,0-8)
all(1,2,0-8)
.
.
.
all(3,2,0-8)
all(3,3,0-8)
```

I want to get the unique value that resides in one of these arrays meaning none of the others has it. How can i do this?

PS: I have lost 10 hours on this and ashamed to share how I extracted them from each other only to find out it did not work for some reason probably something to do with odd numbers so I am noob and put 10 hours of effort in already.

```
i = 1                    'same box probablity elimination

c = 0
e = 0
k = 1
For i = 1 To 3
    For k = 1 To 3
      For c = 0 To 8
      e = 0
       For e = 0 To 8
         If k = 3 And i = 1 Then


            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0



            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
         End If

          If k = 3 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
          End If

          If k = 3 And i = 3 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
          End If

          If k = 2 And i = 1 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 2 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 2 And i = 3 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 1 And i = 1 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
                        If e = 1 And c = 1 And i = 1 And k = 1 Then MsgBox all(3, 1, 0) & all(3, 1, 1) & all(3, 1, 2) & all(3, 1, 3) & all(3, 1, 4) & all(3, 1, 5) & all(3, 1, 6)
                        If e = 1 And c = 1 And i = 1 And k = 1 Then MsgBox all(1, 1, 0) & all(1, 1, 1) & all(1, 1, 2) & all(1, 1, 3) & all(1, 1, 4) & all(1, 1, 5) & all(1, 1, 6)

            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0
                        If e = 1 And c = 1 And i = 1 And k = 1 Then MsgBox all(3, 1, 0) & all(3, 1, 1) & all(3, 1, 2) & all(3, 1, 3) & all(3, 1, 4) & all(3, 1, 5) & all(3, 1, 6)
                        If e = 1 And c = 1 And i = 1 And k = 1 Then MsgBox all(1, 1, 0) & all(1, 1, 1) & all(1, 1, 2) & all(1, 1, 3) & all(1, 1, 4) & all(1, 1, 5) & all(1, 1, 6)

            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 1 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 1 And i = 3 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 2, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 3, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 3, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 3, c) = 0
            End If
           End If
        Next e
      Next c
    Next k
Next i

i = 1                    'same box probablity elimination
c = 0
e = 0
k = 4
For i = 1 To 3
    For k = 4 To 6
      For c = 0 To 8
      e = 0
       For e = 0 To 8
         If k = 6 And i = 1 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 2, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0
            End If
         End If

          If k = 6 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
          End If

          If k = 6 And i = 3 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
          End If

          If k = 5 And i = 1 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 5 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 5 And i = 3 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 2, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 2, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 6, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 4 And i = 1 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 6, c) = 0
            End If
           End If

           If k = 4 And i = 2 Then
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 4, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 5, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i - 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 6, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 6, c) = 0
            End If
           End If
```

EDIT:

I thought of an algorithm which will work with odd numbers of concurring values in those arrays. I only can use if-then, for-next and do-while so it will take some time to implement it.

Basically it will store the concurring value in a separate variable and eliminate them all at once from the arrays instead of on the comparison. Thanks Floris for his inputs anyway.

Comment: Are you saying every value that occurs in each array occurs in at least one other array, except for the specific value you are looking for? What kind of arrays are these? The look "mixed" - some integers, and a string `0-8`. Why not concatenate all the arrays and look for the element that occurs exactly once? You could do this with a `Dictionary` object (if you are running on Windows).

Comment: each array element holds one integer ranging from 0 to 9 and mostly zero nothing else.

Comment: Could you show the actual values (if you have 8x8, there are just 64 values. It should be pretty trivial to show them.) . It would also help to show the code you used to try this - don't be shy. It's easier to fix someone's code than to write something from scratch (usually).

Comment: how can i use dictionary object? i am on windows.

Comment: i = 1                    'same box probablity elimination
c = 0
e = 0
k = 1
For i = 1 To 3
    For k = 1 To 3
      For c = 0 To 8
      e = 0
       For e = 0 To 8
         If k = 3 And i = 1 Then
         

            If all(i, k, e) - all(i, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i, 1, c) = 0
            

            
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 1, 1, c) = 0
            End If
            If all(i, k, e) - all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0 Then
            all(i, k, e) = 0: all(i + 2, 1, c) = 0

Comment: sorry will try editing up

Comment: edited up the original question, thanks for your time.

Comment: Wow - that's quite some code. See if my answer works for you… gotta run for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a variant of the following (it is inefficient in that I create an array with one elements for each possible integer in the range of values in a; but it's a start…)

```
Sub uniqueEl()
Dim a
a = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), _
                Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), _
                Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), _
                Array(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4))

Dim m1, m2
m1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(a)
m2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(a)
Dim b() As Integer
ReDim b(0 To m2 - m1)
Dim c, d
For Each c In a
  For Each d In c
    b(d - m1) = b(d - m1) + 1
  Next
Next

Dim ii
ii = m1
For Each c In b
  If c = 1 Then
    MsgBox "found the single element: it is " & ii
  End If
  ii = ii + 1
Next



End Sub
```

Comment: gonna try this out as soon as i figure how this works, i mean i never used for-each-in statement ever before.

Comment: For each is just shorthand for accessing every element in turn without having to say explicitly how many elements there are. A bit like saying `For ii =LBound(a) To UBound(a): c=a(ii)` etc